# How to create object by it's name?

Tags: unit-test, class, sobject

I'm writing a REST service which calls external service. I want to write a test for my service. I came up with no possibility to mock this call as it's in managed package. I want to wrap this call with Test.isRunninTest() method.
And here is the problem - I can't instantiate a result of this call because... This class doesn't have a constructor.
So I want to instantiate it by it's name. Smth like:

`System.Type t = mngdpckg.WebServiceClass.ResultSmthCoolExt.class;
result = (mngdpckg.WebServiceClass.ResultSmthCoolExt)t.newInstance();`

This code gives me

> FATAL_ERROR|MyCoolService.Exception: Error processing transaction: mngdpckg.WebServiceClass.ResultSmthCoolExt does not have a no-arg constructor

Is there any chance I can get this class' instance in a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only instantiate like this if you have a [no arg constructor](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_newInstance).

If you did have such a constructor, the syntax would be:

```
Type t = Type.forName('mngdpckg.WebServiceClass.ResultSmthCoolExt');
result = t.newInstance();
```

However, you'll end up with the same error as you have stated you don't have a constructor.

From the docs:

> Calling this method on a type corresponding to a class that has a
>   private no-argument constructor results in a System.TypeException, as
>   expected because the type can’t be instantiated. For Apex saved using
>   Salesforce.com API version 28.0 and earlier, this method returns an
>   instance of the class instead.

Which implies that classes on API <=28 will return an Instance, however on testing this:

```
public class TestNoArg {
    private TestNoArg() {}
}

Type t = Type.forName('TestNoArg');
t.newInstance();
```

I still get the exception:

> System.TypeException: TestNoArg does not have a no-arg constructor

Comment: If you are using Type.newInstance(), you should consider replacing the constructor with an init method. init() can be safely called after a type cast. This is much more flexible and opens some room for mocking and replacing types during unit testing.